# How solve"no python application found check your startup logs" error for Django + uWSGI + nginx stack

Tags: django, nginx, ansible, web-deployment, uwsgi

I user Django 1.10 with uWSGI and nginx on ubuntu 16.04 and deploy my app with ansible. My project have not default structure, but quite common ( thank Two scoopce for this :).
I use split dev and production settings and config folder instead 'name' project folder. It's looks like this:

```
|-- config
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- base.py
|   |   `-- dev.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi_dev.py
|   `-- wsgi_production.py
|-- manage.py
`-- requirements.txt
```

My `production.py` genarate from ansible with security encrypt and locate in config/settings.

With this config i get "no python application found check your startup logs". Uwsgi don't see my application.

( {{  }} it's jinja2 syntax for ansible )

`/etc/uwsgi/sites/{{ project_name }}`

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = {{ django_root }}
home = /home/{{ project_user }}/venvs/{{ project_name }}
module = config.wsgi_production:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/{{ project_name }}.sock
chown-socket = {{ project_user }}:www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After several weeks i can find problem in my `wsgi.py`. It common solution use `os.environ['ENV']` for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, but with deffrent users and permissions its dosen't work.

If you use in your `wsgi.py` file something like this:

`os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "config.settings." + os.environ["ENV"]`

And have problem with `no python application found` - split your wsgi file. I can catch that `os.environ["ENV"]` return empty string. I add it for my all user, use source and etc. But uwsgi in emperior mode don't see it.
You sould use `wsgi_dev.py` and `wsgi_production.py` where you can write somethink like this `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "config.settings.production"`. It's not so elegant but solve this problems fine.

For use splitting wsgi you can write something like this in `wsgi.py`

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

if os.environ.get('DEV') is True:
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.dev")
else:
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 
   "config.settings.production")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Hi, how did you split wsgi files?

Comment: For `searx` I found out that I had to run `./manage.sh` with enabled virtual environment. `# Searx virtual environment
alias virtualenv="python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py"
export SEARX_PYENV="${HOME}/searx-ve"
source "${SEARX_PYENV}/bin/activate"
`